# Check if an application is installed or not according to mobile device

Tags: javascript

I have my website and I want that when a user is browsing from his cell phone, I want to detected if it is ios/android and if the user does not have my application installed, that he be redirected to the play store or app store.

But if the user already has the application installed, open the application

For the moment I managed to detect the device, but how can I detect if the app is installed or not? thank you

```
<a id="app_link" href="#" >continue in the app</a>

<script>
const os = (() => {
if (/iphone/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    var link = document.getElementById("app_link");
    link.href = "https://apps.apple.com/app/myapp";
}
else if (/ipad/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    var link = document.getElementById("app_link");
    link.href = "https://apps.apple.com/app/myapp";
}
else if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
    var link = document.getElementById("app_link");
    link.href = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/myapp";
}
})();
```

Comment: You might want to use a premade solution such as smartbanner.js https://github.com/ain/smartbanner.js

Comment: For privacy reasons I doubt you can check. When the application is installed, it makes itself the handler for its URLs. If it's not installed, the user is given the opportunity to install it.